# Event on new user created

Tags: craft3, users, extends

please can someone help me with this snippet of code I have written. I basically would like to check if a user is new. However, the below only triggers when an existing user is saved, not when a new account is created. i would like this to apply only to new users Thanks for any help

```
 Event::on(
        User::class,
        User::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE,
        function (ModelEvent $event) {
            $user = $event->sender;
            $isNew = $event->isNew;
    
            if ($isNew) {
                Craft::info('is new', __METHOD__);
            } else {
                Craft::info('is not new', __METHOD__);
            }
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$isNew = $user->isNewForSite`.

Comment: Here you can get more detail about this
https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-base-elementtrait.html#isnewforsite